# WinUI 3 UWP - Choose appo theme

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-11

I'm developing a WinUI 3 UWP app for Windows 11 and the app automatically defaults to the theme chosen by Windows. Is there any way to give the user the choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can change the theme for your whole application:

```
if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement rootElement)
{
    rootElement.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light; //.Dark, .Default
}
```

Comment: Where does that code go?  I cannot find anything on the internet with a one-liner to change the theme to Dark in Visual Studio 2022.  Everything says to add RequestedTheme to App.xaml but RequestedTheme is no longer a property in Application.  I do not understand why this simple thing is so difficult to find.